# When I get the id of the registered user, I have NULL- ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I currently have an error. I have a login that works fine for me, user registration works super well, I also have a post method called (`LoadMarket`).

```
[HttpPost("LoadMarket")]
public async Task<ActionResult> LoadMarket(MercadoDTO marketDTO)
{
    try
    {
        var market = mapper.Map<Mercado>(marketDTO);

        var email = HttpContext.User.Claims
                               .Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email)
                               .First().Value;

        var usuarioActual = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

        market.UserId = usuarioActual.Id;
        _dataContext.Mercados.Add(market);

        await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync();

        return Ok("Datos Ingresados");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest($"An error has occurred {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

This method works well, it fulfills the requirement of saving an object of type `Market` and saving the ID of the person who made it.

The problem I have is when I want to get the whole list of registrations made by that user.

```
[HttpGet("GetAllMarket")]
public async Task<ActionResult<List<OptenerMercadoDTO>>> GetMarket()
{
        try
        {
            // Gets the Id of the current user
            var userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            if (userId == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            // Filter the markets by the current user's
            var mercados = await _dataContext.Mercados
                .Where(m => m.UserId == userId)
                .ToListAsync();
                
            return mapper.Map<List<OptenerMercadoDTO>>(mercados);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest($"Error en la solicitud: {ex.Message}");
        }
}
```

What happens is that when I want to get all the records made by a person: `userId` is Null.

```
var userId =  User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
```

Thank you if you can help me

Comment: Which authentication you have used? Identity or Identity server or else?  Did your web api protected by them?